# How do I stop emacs from clearing the screen in MinGW?

Tags: git-bash, mingw, mingw64

I'm getting some odd behavior in MinGW on Windows.

Every time I open emacs in the terminal emulator (`emacs -nw`), I find that when I close out of it that terminal has cleared itself.

For example, if I run `mypy` I get a list of Python type errors. Then I can open the offending code file and fix one of them, but then when I close out of it, I have lost the output of `mypy` and have to run it again to see the next error.

I've tried searching but I'm buried in results for how to keep the output of `less` after pressing `q`, but that's a question about `less` specifically whereas this is an issue with the terminal emulator itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a bug report that seems to describe your problem :
[Error list is cleared upon editing Rust file #1480](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1480).

> When modifying Rust (.rs) files, the error list is cleared out until the file is saved.
> describe-variable says that flycheck-check-syntax-automatically is (save idle-change new-line mode-enabled). I have not set it manually; it is probably managed by spacemacs. For other languages/checkers, linting/error appears on the fly. I understand that checking/linting Rust is particularly expensive and that doing it on the fly is perhaps not desirable; **I just want the error list not to clear when editing the file**.

This bug was discussed from 2018 to 2020, but was never assigned to
any developer. Its current status is "help wanted" (I'm not kidding)
now in 2022.

I can see here these options for you :

- Ensure that all the software packages involved are fully updated
- Copy the errors list elsewhere before editing, to save it before it's
  cleared
- Create a new bug report (with the details from your environment)
  and keep demanding for it to be solved.